# Why do the litre and cubic metre volumes of cylinder natural gas not correspond?

Tags: pressure, gas, volume

A $47L$ cylinder says it contains $8.4m^3$ of natural gas at $137$ bar pressure.

Could someone explain how we get from $47L$ to $8.4m^3$ ?

I’m not an expert and thought they should be different by a factor of $1000$.

Link: https://www.boconline.co.uk/shop/en/uk/natural-gas-cylinder

Comment: Have you factored in the pressure?

Comment: It is a misprint. On the web page top right is written *Natural Gas, BS4, 47 litre (J Size), Steel Cylinder, 137 Bar* and bottom left *Natural gas cylinder, supplied in cylinder size J (8.4m3 volume) with a pressure of 137bar.*  I assume that 47 litres at 137 Bar become 8.3m^3 at 1 Bar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *A 47 l cylinder [...] contains 8.4 m^3 of natural gas at 137 bar pressure.*

This statement is just terse enough to seem paradox (to any naive non-expert).
More explicitly and thus correctly we might say:

"A 47 l cylinder contains 47 l of compressed natural gas, at 137 bar pressure. If the cylinder is opened, the content escapes and its pressure is equilized to atmospheric pressure of 1 bar, then we have 8.4 m^3 of natural gas."

**EDIT**

Treating "natural gas" (at roughly room temperature) approximately as [ideal gas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ideal_gas#Classical_thermodynamic_ideal_gas), and the expansion process mentioned above as approximately isothermal (i.e. proceding at constant temperature), pressure and volume should be (accordingly roughly) inverse proportional (cmp. "Boyle's law"):
$$ V \propto \frac{1}{P}. $$

But instead of

$$ 47~{\rm l} * 137~{\rm bar} =(?)= 8400~{\rm l} * 1~{\rm bar} $$

I find a much better fit with another value for the ("expanded", "depressurized") natural gas volume, namely:

$$ 47~{\rm l} * 137~{\rm bar} == 6439~{\rm l} * 1~{\rm bar}. $$

So, arguably, we should rather talk about "6.4 m^3 of natural gas".